# Checking if kendo grid row exists with Selenium-IDE

Tags: selenium, kendo-grid, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium-IDE to find out does a particular row exist.

I can run the following command on the firefox console that'll show me the row,

```
$('#GridName').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()[0]
```

This will display the object (first table row) in the console but I'm not to sure how to work with it, or how to execute the above code using selenium-IDE. This is my question, how can I use the IDE to execute this on the console and how can I work with the output?

I can't use ID's or Xpaths for this and I'm limited to the IDE for the moment. I know it's not easy but I have to be able to try via this command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `runScript` command in Selenium IDE

```
<tr>
  <td>runScript</td>
  <td>$('#GridName').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data()[0]</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I ask though what this is doing? the runScript line will run green and continue with the test even if I leave it blank, I'm just not sure what it's actually doing. Is this javaScript it runs going anywhere? I'm trying to see if the object that line returns exists is all.